# Is yarn compatible with importmaps-rails in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I just installed Rails 7 with bootstrap.
It didn't come with import maps by default.

Can I use import maps with yarn, or should I stick to one method only?

Is there any compatibility issue I should be aware of?

If using both, what application.js would look like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Bootstrap css framework requires SASS and SASS is a Node module.  When you specify that you want to use Bootstrap, your project is switched to a ESBuild one. It is not possible to have Importmap and Bootstrap in the same Rails 7.0.0 project.

Have a look on the following files:

- bin/dev
- Procfile.dev
- package.json

At this time, the only CSS framework that does not require Node is Tailwindcss

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and solves my issue.

Comment: You should really mark the answer as correct so others know you got an answer and those with a similar answer can find a solution faster too!